# Magento configure a product while comparing

Tags: php, magento, compare, product, configurable

I'd like to add some functionality to the comparing feature Magento offers. When comparing products, users are presented with an 'Add to cart' button. This feature only works well for simple products. When pressing the add to cart button on a configurable or bundled product the user is redirected to the product detail, out of the compare view.

*Would it not be much better when a user could configure the products inside the compare view?!*

Do you guys know of a magento plugin that does this trick? Or have ideas how this feature could be implemented in the existing source?

Answer (score 0):

This is something that comes up from time to time as I develop Magento sites. The gist of the problem is this: the logic for dealing with configurable/bundle/etc products is not simple. The JS code that was written to handle this convoluted logic is written is such a way that multiple products on the same page cannot be accomodated.

So, to do what you want, the first thing to do is to simplify your products down significantly. The brunt of the complexity is dealing with multiple configurable attributes and changing pricing, etc. After that, you'll need to rewrite the configurable product JS to set up the submit form properly. Once you get the right data submitted, you should be pretty safe.

Hope that gives you a hint!

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: What i'm trying to do in the end is enhancing the existing compare functionality and make it load the selected products. Thanks for your pointer by the way :)